# How call a superclass implementation of a method that takes a variable number of arguments as in [UIAlertView initWithTitle...]?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, variables, methods, arguments

The OS X Developer Library shows how to create a method that takes a variable number of args in the following technical article: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1405/_index.html.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to subclass an existing implementation of method that takes variable args and call the superclass implementation.

Using UIActionSheet as an example look at the code below. Calling the superclass initWithTitle method only passes the first 'otherButtonTitle'. I don't know how to pass the remaining strings contained in the variable argument list.

```
// MyActionSheet.m

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title
           delegate:(id < UIActionSheetDelegate >)delegate
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle
destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle
otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    // this calls the superclass initWithTitle: method but does not
    // pass NIL terminated list of strings
    self = [super initWithTitle:title
                       delegate:delegate
              cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
         destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle
              otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles, nil];
    if (self) {
        // custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```

I can get the args using va_list, va_start, va_end but don't know how to pass them to the superclass method.

In case anyone is tempted to tell me that I can do this a different way (e.g. don't pass along the variable args but use va_list, va_start, va_end to create an array of strings and call addButtonWithTitle: multiple times, I know I can do that. I used UIActionSheet as an example. There are other cases where the ability to subclass a method with variable args would be useful and I'd like to learn how to do exactly what I've asked if it is possible.

thanks!

Comment: Do you need `nil` on the end of `otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles, nil];` if `otherButtonTitles` variable is already a nil terminated list?

Comment: You do need the nil. The `otherButtonTitles` argument only contains the first string in the list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A number of classes in Cocoa have methods that take variable numbers of arguments. In most cases, these classes will also have an equivalent method that takes a va_list. It's only possible to do what you're suggesting if the class you're using provides one of those methods. For instance, +[NSString stringWithFormat:...] takes a variable number of arguments. Cocoa provides -[NSString initWithFormat:arguments:] where the arguments parameter is a va_list. This allows you to do the following:

```
- (void)setContentsWithFormat:(NSString *)formatString, ... {
    [contents autorelease];

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, formatString);
    contents = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:formatString arguments:args];
    va_end(args);
}
```

The va_list parameter allows us to pass our own variable argument list to the Cocoa method so that the Cocoa method can handle the arguments.

However, since UIAlertView doesn't provide a va_list API, the cleanest way is probably to make repeated calls to addButtonWithTitle:

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Objective-C's variable arguments support is effectively that of C, and as you may already know there is no (portable) way to correctly set up the stack to call to a variadic function.

If the designer of the superclass was on the ball, there will be a parallel function that takes a `va_list` or NSArray argument that you can call instead. If not, you're usually out of luck.

In this particular case, you could call the superclass's constructor with `nil` for all the buttons, and then use `addButtonWithTitle:`, `cancelButtonIndex`, and so on to setup the buttons "manually".

Answer (score 0):

If you can't do it the proper way, you can always do this:

```
id arg1 = ...; // nil or 1st arg
id arg2 = ...; // nil or 2nd arg
id arg3 = ...; // nil or 3rd arg
id arg4 = ...; // nil or 4th arg
// etc.

self = [super initWithTitle:title
                   delegate:delegate
          cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
     destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle
          otherButtonTitles:arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,/*etc*/ nil];
```

ugly as hell, but it will work.

Comment: You would have to know exactly how many args are passed in with this approach.

Comment: Sure? I thought the point of a nil terminated list was that it terminates on the nil. Also I see no problems in a quick test, supplying a `UIAlertView` this as the last argument: `@"OK",nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil`

Comment: agreed, this will work but too ugly for me to consider unless I was desperate. and it does have the limitation that it will only support the max number of args you hard code as `arg` vars.